# Spark hbase bulk load generates more than 15X data

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, bulk-load

I have Spark dataframe with just 2 columns like `{ Key| Value}`. And this dataframe has 10 million records. I am inserting this into HBase table (has 10 pre-split regions) using bulk load approach from Spark. This works fine and loads the data successfully. When I checked the size table it was like 151GB (453 gb with 3x hadoop replication). I ran major compaction on that table, and table size got reduced to 35GB (105gb with 3x replication).

I am trying to run the same code and same data in a different cluster. But here I have quota limitation of 2TB to my namespace. My process fails while loading HFiles to HBase saying its quota limit exceeded.

I would like to know whether Spark creates much more data files than the required 151GB during the bulk load? If so how to avoid that? or is there better approach to load the same?

The question is that if actual data is around 151gb (before `major_compact`), then why 2TB size is not enough?